# Show form control value in div

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-material, angular-forms

I have an angular reactive nested form.

```
this.productsForm = new FormGroup({
        "products": this.productFormArray
      });
    });
  }

  getProducts() {
    var ctrls = (<FormArray>this.productsForm.get('products')).controls;
    return ctrls;
  }
```

I am iterating a form array and successfully setting values in the inputs

```
<div form [formGroup]="productsForm" >
<table formArrayName="products">
    <tr *ngFor="let element of getProducts(); let i=index"  [formGroupName]="i">
    <td>
    <input formControlName="productCode" />
    <span formControlName="productCode">{{element.productCode}}</span>
    </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

However, I can't set a same value in span. Is there amy way to do that?

Comment: Your question is very unclear. Setting formControlName on a span doesn't make sense: how could you possibly enter or select a value using a span? It's not a form control. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: My form includes inputs and the values that I have just to show. All the values are in the form array. So, some of the values I need just to show and the other to set in inputs. It is a reason why I am using span along with the input field

Comment: So you want to show the value of a form control? Use `FormControl.value`: https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#value. And to get the form control by its name from a FormGroup, use `FormGroup.get()`: https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#get. It's quite strange to use a FormControl for a read-only value that is not meant to be edited/entered  by the user.

Comment: `{{element.value.productCode}}`. Your FormArray is a serie of FormGroup, when you iterate over FormArrray.controls, element is the formGroup, so element.value is the value of the formGroup TIP: Sometimes it's util write in .html {{element.value|json}}, CURIOSITY, we can use a input like `<input [formControl]="element.get('productCode')"/>`

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it by iterating over an initial array instead of form. I normal form with only inputs I would iterate over form. However here I need to iterate over array.
So, instead of

```
<div form [formGroup]="productsForm" >
<table formArrayName="products">
    <tr *ngFor="let element of getProducts(); let i=index"  [formGroupName]="i">
    <td>
    <input formControlName="productCode" />
    <span formControlName="productCode">{{element.productCode}}</span>
    </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

I am using now:

```
<div form [formGroup]="productsForm" >
    <table formArrayName="products">
        <tr *ngFor="let element of dataSource; let i=index"  [formGroupName]="i">
        <td>
        <input formControlName="productCode" />
        <span formControlName="productCode">{{element.productCode}}</span>
        </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </div>
```

Maybe anyone has a better solution?

Comment: if you has a dataSource (an array of object), I would prefer use the first one code and dataSource[i].propertyFixed (For me It's better iterate using the FormArray.controls and use  auxiliar data and the "index" to show inmutable properties)